# Open source test management tools

Tags: test-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for test management tool to integrate with JIRA, Hudson, SoapUI, and Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5246/looking-for-test-management-tool-to-integrate-with-jira-hudson-soapui-and-sel)

I'm looking for an open source test management tool. Our application is written in Java and the UI is web UI.

I need to integrate it with JIRA.