# Looking for test management tool to integrate with JIRA, Hudson, SoapUI, and Selenium

Tags: test-management

I'm checking an open source test management tool for my company. The main options are [Xqual](http://xqual.com/) and [Testlink](http://www.teamst.org/).

In the past I worked on Testlink, played a bit with Xstudio.

Our product is written in Java, and has Web UI.

It need to have good integration with JIRA, Hudson, SoapUI, Selenium.

I'm looking for opinion form people that worked on both of them.

Comment: Have you tried to search on the Web? What have you found?

Comment: Looks like this question is an update to your previous quesion http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/open-source-test-management-tools. Could you update your previous question by editing it, instead of multiplying questions about the same?

Comment: Also you mention Xstudio and Xqual but they are the same product, namely XQual Studio. Correct?

Comment: What's you're experience so far with TestLink and XStudio?

Comment: Why do you want test management tool that integrates with SoapUI if your app's only interface is, as far as I understood, Web UI?

Comment: @dzieciou Thanks for the heads up on the duplicate - I've closed the previous q as a dupe (given that this version had more information), and merged the questions.

Comment: @testarab, Right. I've just suggested closing the other one, which seems less complete. Joe Strazzare's answer could be merged here, though.

Comment: All done - thanks :) (sorry if the above looks confusing, I should stop editing comments as I always seem to get a reply come in before I save the edit!)

Answer (score 3):

**Testlink** is still the leader a lot on the open-source market however there has not been much changes in the last years and some people start saying it's a dying project :( maybe just a rumor but anyway it's not been very active recently... IMHO **XStudio** is the best choice by far. It has great features and it's growing fast. It has even better features than QC in some area and the list of interfaces to test automation framework supported is impressive (Selenium, Webdriver, SoapUI are included).
The good thing also is that XQual provide an optional commercial support (same model as MySql).
Just my 2 cents,

Answer (score 1):

+1 for XStudio.
We integrated more than 4 automated test frameworks with our XStudio instance 2 years ago and it's doing the job nicely.
I recommend it.

Edit: Btw, yes XQual and XStudio is the same thing. XQual is the brand, XStudio is their product.

Comment: What test frameworks have you integrated?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few you might wish to check out:
http://www.opensourcetesting.org/testmgt.php

Answer (score 0):

TestLink  1.9.4 has been released on September 2012.
TestLink is also offered by BitNami as installer or VM
TestLink 1.9.5 will be released on Dic 2012, with tight integration with BTS allowing you to create issues directly from TestLink.
You can also can have payed support if needed (ask to testlink.forum@gmail.com)
You can also can have payed onsite training (on Europe)

Comment: With which BTS?